# Vector Calculus, Parametrization of a parallel line?

Tags: calculus

The line passing by $(1,2,4)$ and parallel to r(t) = $(2+t, 1-t, 7+2t)$.

Basically I started like this I plug in (1,2,4) to r(t) and got for xyz 1,2,3,

$(3,0,9), (4,-1,11), (6,-3,15).$ How does one  derive the answer after this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $r$ has equation: $\vec x= t(1,-1,2)^T+(2,1,7)^T$ so it is parallel to the vector $\vec u=(1,-1,2)^T$.

A line parallel to the same vector and passing thorough $(1,2,4)$ has equation:
$$
\vec x= t(1,-1,2)^T+(1,2,4)^T
$$

Comment: How did you get (1,-1,2)?

Comment: they are the coefficents of $t$ in your line.

Comment: So you subtracted (4,-1,11) - (3,0,9) correct?

Comment: You don't need such a calculus. Simply read the equation of the line as: $(x,y,z)=(2+t,1-t,7+2t)=(2,1,7)+(t,-t,2t)=(2,1,7)+t(1,-1,2)$.

Comment: So there is no addition you just read the equation and separated the t.

Comment: Yes! It's simple :)